# How to prove this inequality? about norm and indicator function.

Tags: statistics, inequality, normed-spaces

$$\sup_{\boldsymbol{\beta}': \Vert\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\beta}'\Vert\leq \varepsilon_n} |\mathbb{1}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}^T\boldsymbol{\beta} <C)-\mathbb{1}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}' <C)| \leq \Vert\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\Vert\{\mathbb{1}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}-\varepsilon_n <C)-\mathbb{1}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}'+\varepsilon_n <C)\}.$$
Maybe I forget some properties of $\Vert\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\beta}'\Vert\leq \varepsilon_n$ thus this proof is easy but I can't understand. Hope someone can answer this question.

Comment: Is something missing on the right side of the inequality? On the left side, you're taking the supremum over a set of $\beta'$. On the right side, you just have a $\beta'$ with no sup, inf, etc.

Comment: Oh...this paper doesn't show any sup or inf, so I feel confused :( I think it is maybe about some neighborhood properties?

Comment: Is this exactly how it's written in the paper? Without any absolute values on the right side or assumptions about $\|x\|$?

Comment: Yes, this is given in the proof of a Lemma, and said "It's easy to verify that". Assume $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm.